# Dephi dbgrid selected cells's field name

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi programming and I am struggling to find information on how to get the field name of a selected cell in a DBgrid. 
Because I want to be able to edit that cell that is selected.
I hope someone can help.

Comment: you select an entire row, not a single cell.

Comment: I tried to answer your question. I hope it fits your needs. For a more detailed answer, you should ask your question in a more detailed way. The more information you provide, the better answers you'll get.

Comment: It's not clear from your q whether you want to change the value *in code* of the field associated with the selected/focused cell, or allow the user to edit the value in the cell.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

**Welcome to Stack Overflow!**

You can find a comprehensive documentation of the `TDBGrid` component in [Embarcadero's DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid).

What you really want to edit is probably the underlying fields values, as you chose the data-aware component rather than a more simple `TStringGrid`. For that, there is a [property `Fields`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.Fields) which can be accessed with an index for each field in the grids dataset. There even is a [`SelectedField` property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.SelectedField) returning the currently selected field.

For example, you can set the selected field's value to a string 'Hello World!' like this:

```
MyGrid.SelectedField.AsString := 'Hello World!';
```

Note, that you're accessing the data via dataset. Therefore, you change only the selected record's data.